# Removing Markers from Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cannot seem to figure out why the markers that I am adding to a Google Map, are not being removed properly.

I am adding and removing markers, based on a list that is returned to me through a callback. This list changes every 10 seconds, and return a set of objects that contain a preset key/id. There can be an object that is returned with the same exact String key/id every 10 seconds, as long as it is within a specific radius.

I am checking to see if a marker within the markersHashMap (represents markers on the Google Map) is contained within the new markersCurrentHashMap. If the ID does not exist in the markersCurrentHashMap (because the object is out of range/radius), I am removing that entries Marker from the Google Map, and then I am removing the entry from the HashMap.

**How come my Marker is not being removed properly, even though the Key/Value pair is being removed properly from the markersHashMap?**

This line seems to be the problem.. `markersHashMap.get(key).remove();`

**Here is how I am adding/removing specific markers based on this returned list.**

```
private void updateMapMarkers(List<AnimateCarObj> carAnimateCarList) {
    animateCarObjMap.clear();
    markersCurrentHashMap.clear();

    //POPULATE CURRENT HASHMAP / ANIMATE CAR MAP
    for (AnimateCarObj ao : carAnimateCarList) {
        if (ao.isAnimating()) {
            isAnimCacheCarList.add(ao);
        }
        addAnimCarObjToMap(ao);
        addMarkerToCurrentHashMap(ao);
    }
    printAnimateCarMap();
    printCurrentMarkerMap();

    //REMOVE ALL MARKERS FROM MARKER MAP, THAT DO NOT EXIST IN THE CURRENT VIEWABLE LIST
    //removeOldMarkers();
    for (String key : markersHashMap.keySet()) {
        if (!(markersCurrentHashMap.containsKey(key))) {
            markersHashMap.get(key).remove();
            markersHashMap.remove(key);
        }
    }
    addNewMarkers();
    printMarkerMap();
}
```

**How markers are added**

```
public void addNewMarkers() {
    for (String key : markersCurrentHashMap.keySet()) {
        if(!markersHashMap.containsKey(key)){
            addMarker(key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Adding creating the marker, adding to hashmap**

```
public void addMarker(String id) {
    AnimateCarObj animateCarObj = animateCarObjMap.get(id);
    Bitmap carIcon = IconUtils.loadIcon(getActivity(), "some_car_marker.png", 0,
                                                                            (int) DisplayUtils.dp2pixel(getActivity(), 50), ScaleMode.BY_HEIGHT);

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(animateCarObj.getGps1())
                                                                .rotation((float) animateCarObj.getWs_CarInfoObj().getBearing())
                                                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(carIcon))
                                                                .visible(true));

    addMarkerToHashMap(id, marker);
}
```

**Adding marker to hashmap**

```
public void addMarkerToHashMap(String id, Marker marker) {
    setUpMarkersHashMap();
    markersHashMap.put(id, marker);
}
```

**Here is how the HashMaps are initialized**

```
public void setUpMarkersHashMap() {
    if (animateCarObjMap == null) {
        animateCarObjMap = new HashMap<String, AnimateCarObj>();
    }

    if (markersHashMap == null) {
        markersHashMap = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
    }

    if (markersCurrentHashMap == null) {
        markersCurrentHashMap = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
    }

    if (markersResultHashMap == null) {
        markersResultHashMap = new HashMap<String, Marker>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not properly removed ? The markers are still visible on the map ?

Comment: Yes. The markers do not ever get removed from the map. I need to remove each marker on a case by case basis.

Comment: Does the remove block satisfy this condition  `if (!(markersCurrentHashMap.containsKey(key)))` ?  Did you check if the code reached inside that if block ?

Comment: Yes, when it is time to remove an object, it makes it passed that code.

Comment: After you remove markers, you add markers with `addNewMarkers`. Are you sure they are the same markers ? If you remove this method `addNewMarkers` do the markers get removed from the map ?

Comment: The addNewMarkers method checks to see if any of the new object ids already exist within the old cached hashmap, if they do it doesn't do anything, but if they don't exist (meaning they are not on the google map) than it will add them.

Comment: In your `addMarkerToHashMap()`, you are calling to `setUpMarkersHashMap();`. Maybe you are doing some kind of initialisation here that is clearing your `HashMap`. Could you post the code of `setUpMarkersHashMap()`?

Comment: I just posted the code for setUpMarkersHashMap();

Comment: Yes I know that. I want to know if you mistake new markers with old markers and see if `markersHashMap.remove(key);` works by not adding more markers to the map.